# What is the right way to set MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY for different configurations?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

In the windows environment and Visual Studio 2019 IDE, what is the right way to set `MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` for two different configurations `Test_Debug` and `Debug` which are both `DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS`?
Somehow this is does not work:

```
add_executable(foo foo.c)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
  MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>"
  MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Test_Debug>:Debug>")
```

Could somebody advise the right way to go about it?

Comment: `"MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>$<$<CONFIG:Test_Debug>:Debug>"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set any property twice in the same `set_target_properties` call, you *overwrite* the previous setting. So, only the **last** setting is applied:

```
MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Test_Debug>:Debug>"
```

---

If you want to set the `MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` to `MultiThreadedDebug` when the configuration is `Debug` or `Test_Debug`, you can use the `OR` [logical operator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#logical-operators) generator expression:

```
$<OR:conditions>
```

So the full expression would be:

```
set_target_properties(MyExe1 PROPERTIES
    MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY 
        "MultiThreaded$<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:Test_Debug>>:Debug>"
)
```